# VB.NET controlling form from other classes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

I am studying VB.NET

I am trying to control form element from other class.

What I can do is , I can create reference Object which is Form1 to control element in Form1

Code on the blow , i used "Form1.Label1.Text = 1 " to control element in Form1

However, I would like to control element in Form without accessing Form1 directly

This there anyway to control Form from other classes ?

For example , we have.. we have two labels in the Form1 class and I want to change label text from another class

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Book


    Public Sub test()
        Form1.Label1.Text = 1  
    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an instance of the form when showing it. Then set up events in the class of the other form and when something changes you just raise the event. This event must be subscribed by the other form's class then, so that it recognizes that and receieves the event.

Comment: Can you give me any kind of link for tutorial(or sample code). I just start to learn VB.NET , so I am not really sure how to do it .. :(

Comment: There you go. Make sure always to create a instance, it is the right way and has lots of advantags. So do always: 'Dim frm As New Form2' and such things. Also make sure to get Option Strict On, just search for google on this because you can't set an integer (1) as a text (string) and so on. Like I said in the comment in the code.

Answer (score 0):

as you were told you have to create an instance of the form like this.

```
dim oForm1 as new Form1
```

Then you can manipulate any of the controls in that form. Just make sure your class Form1 is accessible(public or friend modifier)

```
oForm1.textbox1.text = "Hello"
```